# Oscillating UIView With Stopping Motion (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation

I need a view to enter the screen with oscillating animation and finally, the animation should stop in a natural way (decreasing oscillations - pendulum effect). I have added the subview above the screen so that the view rotates into the screen when required. The code for adding the subview is:

```
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);

[[self view] addSubview:myView];
[myView setHidden:YES];
// Rotate 75 degrees to hide it off screen
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_RADIANS(75));
bannerView.transform = rotationTransform;
bannerView.center = CGPointMake(((self.view.bounds.size.width)/2.0), -5.0);

[self performSelector:@selector(animateSwing) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

The way I'm trying to achieve this that the view should rotate one full semi circle & back rotation, then rotate one semi circle rotation and finally come to halt at desired point using EaseOut animation curve. The code for my `animateSwing()` method is given below:

```
- (void)animateSwing {
     NSLog(@"ANIMATING");
    [myView setHidden:NO];
    CGAffineTransform swingTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    swingTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(swingTransform, DEGREES_RADIANS(-20));


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.30
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1.5];
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];  
                     myView.transform = swingTransform;

                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.10
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                      animations:^{
                                          myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(0));
                                      }completion:^(BOOL Finished){

                                      }];

    }]; 
}
```

For some reason the above code isn't working. If I do not chain animations, the code performs the semi-circle routine. But if I chain animations like above, it just oscillates a little bit around the desired point and ends abruptly.

Please suggest a fix to this code **OR** suggest a way to implement the required animation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a keyframe animation. I actually have an example of a "decreasing waggle" animation in my book (http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_keyframe_animation):

```
CompassLayer* c = (CompassLayer*)self.compass.layer;
NSMutableArray* values = [NSMutableArray array];
[values addObject: @0.0f];
int direction = 1;
for (int i = 20; i < 60; i += 5, direction *= -1) { // alternate directions
    [values addObject: @(direction*M_PI/(float)i)];
}
[values addObject: @0.0f];
CAKeyframeAnimation* anim =
    [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
anim.values = values;
anim.additive = YES;
anim.valueFunction =
    [CAValueFunction functionWithName: kCAValueFunctionRotateZ];
[c.arrow addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Of course that isn't identical to what you're trying to do, but it should get you started.

Comment: I tried running your code without any modification to understand how it works. I commented out your CompassLayer declaration (first line) and modified the last line to [myView.layer addAnim....]. When I try to run it on device, I get the error: _kCAValueFunctionRotateZ and KeyFrameAnimation symbol(s) not found in architecture armv7..

Comment: Downloadable plug-and-play version here (case 8): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/ch16p457compass/p347p358compass/ViewController.m

Comment: Didn't work. I downloaded the xcodeproj file from there and simply tried to run, which didnt run!

Comment: It does run. - However, if my explanation of a keyframe animation is not helpful to you, try Apple's: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Comment: Thanks..If you only you could put that link on top as your answer, i can then mark it as correct :)

Comment: My answer *is* correct. I gave you a link that pointed you to an even better explanation of a keyframe animation (in my opinion).